# Send data from Nodejs to Angular 10

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, angular10

I am using MEAN stack and creating a login system for it. I am trying to do Google Oauth using passport-google-oauth20 in nodejs with Angular 10 as frontend. I am also creating JWT for it. Inside Angular 10, I am directly using

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:9000/auth/google'
```

to call the get request of my nodes server. After google login and creating JWT, I am doing

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/dashboard/'+encodeURI(JSON.stringify(info)))
```

with JWT and some user info. How can I achieve that securely? Here, I am passing it as URL parameters but I feel from security point of view that is not safe. Also, where can I securely store this JWT on the frontend for authorizing other requests?

Answer (score 0):

Doing via the querystring is not going to be secure, granted the token itself should be encrypted but other elements of the token are just base64, so storing the token securely is done via a secure cookie.

Depending on your use case you can also do this as a 'runtime' variable where you store the token in memory, so each time the user refreshes the page they need to request a new token but if you want users to be able to re-use the token then you would store that in a secure cookie